# RabbitMQ Client, connects fine locally, but not on test server

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I have written a simple RabbitMQ Publisher with help from RabbitMQ .NET Client. Basically we have this internal app, and when that wishes to send out emails, I want the emails to be published onto a RabbitMQ Queue, where another consumer app (console app running as a windows service) would then pick those emails up and send them off via SMTP.

This all works fine locally when I use `localhost` as `HostName` and the default `guest` account. But when I change things to the RabbitMQ Test Server, I get an error:

```
<add key="RabbitMQ.HostName" value="rabbit@XXXXX-LTXXX01"/>
<add key="RabbitMQ.UserName" value="adminAccount"/>
<add key="RabbitMQ.Password" value="adminPassword"/>
<add key="RabbitMQ.QueueName" value="DigitalEmails"/>
<add key="RabbitMQ.ExchangeName" value="DigitalEmailsExchange"/>
<add key="RabbitMQ.RoutingKey" value="DigitalEmail"/>
```

The error I get says:

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException - None of the specified endpoints were reachable

It sounds like a permission issue, but I have looked at the `adminAccount` and he seems to be setup like `guest` is. With all permissions granted.

Why is this happening?

**UPDATE**

I tried ping that `HostName` and I got:

[image: ping]

Comment: Can you connect to the same host/IP and port via a manual method?

Comment: If you ping that hostname/IP that you have for "RabbitMQ.HostName", does it resolve?

Comment: See updated question.